# Can I retrieve a property value from a parent model, without a DB relationship between child and parent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parent-child

I have an application serving multiple websites and would like to setup colour scheming like this:

- Each element (link, text, heading, etc) has a default for the application
- Each element can be overridden for individual websites
- If an element is set to application default, the custom colour should be remembered for future reference

---

**Website Configuration.cs**

```
public class WebsiteConfiguration
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration ApplicationConfiguration { get; set; }

    public string CustomLinkColour { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomLinkColourActive { get; set; }
    public string LinkColour 
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsCustomLinkColourActive ? CustomLinkColour : ApplicationConfiguration.DefaultLinkColour);
        }
    }

    public string CustomTextColour { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomTextColourActive { get; set; }
    public string TextColour 
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsCustomTextColourActive ? CustomTextColour : ApplicationConfiguration.DefaultTextColour);
        }
    }

    // ...and so on for each colour scheme element...
}
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.cs**

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    public List<WebsiteConfiguration> WebsiteConfigurations { get; set; }
    public string DefaultLinkColour { get; set; }
    public string DefaultTextColour { get; set; }
    //... and so on for each colour scheme element...
}
```

---

**Problems**

It's a lot of work!

There are just 2 colour scheme elements in the examples above, but there may be 50+ of them.

Also, it is creating a lot of work in the view files, with `if else` blocks etc.

---

**Attempted Solution**

A `ColourSchemeItem` class manages the logic.

```
public class ColourSchemeItem
{
    public string DefaultColour { get; set; }
    public string CustomColour { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomColourActive { get; set; }
    public string ActiveColour
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsCustomColourActive ? CustomColour : DefaultColour);
        }
    }
}
```

And then `WebsiteConfiguration` becomes much simpler...

```
public class WebsiteConfiguration
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration ApplicationConfiguration { get; set; }

    public ColourSchemeItem Link { get; set; }
    public ColourSchemeItem Text { get; set; }

    // ...and so on for each colour scheme element...
}
```

**However...**

But somehow I need to get the default colour from the `ApplicationConfiguration` into the `ColourSchemeItem`. And I can't figure out how.

- If the `ColourSchemeItem` contains a reference to it's parent - `WebsiteConfiguration` - I get a `No Key Defined for Entity` error.
- If ColourSchemeItem does NOT contain a reference to it's parent, I can't access the default colour from `WebsiteConfiguration.ApplicationConfiguration`.
- The only other option I can think of it to access the DB directly from within the `ColourSchemeItem`class. If there are going to be 50+ of these, I don't want to do that.

Comment: Are WebsiteConfiguration and ApplicationConfiguration EF DB classes? Why don't you create the ApplicationConfiguration class as abstract and make WebsiteConfiguration classes inherit from it? In this way you will avoid a lot of if then.

Comment: Yes they are. I'll update the question to make it clearer.  Would inheriting save me code? I think I'd still need to declare 3 properties for each item (as in the first code sample above). And that's what I'm trying to avoild

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom constructor, and set the default to AplicationConfiguration